# Can saltstack update it self then highstate?

Tags: mercurial, yaml, bitbucket, salt-stack

Salt stack is being used with [bit bucket](http://bitbucket.org). There are 2-3 of us who push updates to it occasionaly. I was wondering is there a way where salt stack can get the latest changes from bit bucket then highstate? If so, how would you go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the hgfs backend. whenever a state.highstate is called, the master will pull from bitbucket and send it to the minion. A basic configuration would be the following:

```
fileserver_backend:
  - hg

hgfs_remotes:
  - https://self@bitbucket.org/self/salt

hgfs_branch_method: branches
```

There is unfortuntaley a lack of documentation about how to configure hgfs so doing anything more advance may require you to dig around. Good luck.

Note for future readers: I am not sure whether the minion or the master pulls from bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a [webhook](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Bitbucket+hooks) in BitBucket to call [salt-api](http://salt-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to do a `salt-run fileserver.update` followed by a `state.highstate`.